# Use trigger to insert row if value was changed

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I have the following "dogs" table.

```
+----+------+-------+--------+-------+-----+
| id | Name | Color |  Size  | Hair  | Age |
+----+------+-------+--------+-------+-----+
|  1 | Fido | Red   | Big    | Long  |   4 |
|  2 | Bud  | Red   | Small  | Short |   7 |
|  3 | Sox  | Blue  | Medium | Short |   3 |
+----+------+-------+--------+-------+-----+
```

If one or more value is changed such as `UPDATE dogs SET Name="Bud", Color="redish", Age=8 WHERE id=2;`, I would like to insert several rows in two other tables:

```
INSERT INTO audits(id,auditTable,auditPK,dateTime) VALUES (0,'dogs',2,NOW());
INSERT INTO auditFields(id,auditsId,changeField,oldValue,newValue) VALUES (0,123,'Color','Red','Redish');
INSERT INTO auditFields(id,auditsId,changeField,oldValue,newValue) VALUES (0,123,'Age',7,8);
```

auditsId is the autoincrement ID of the first insert.  Note that there was not an insert for the Name changing since it remained as "Bud".  I am considering normalizing auditTable and changeField, but am not certain whether I should.

Is this possible to do with triggers?  If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER tg_dogs_upd AFTER UPDATE ON dogs
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    SET @AID = 0;
    IF NEW.name <> OLD.name THEN
        IF @AID = 0 THEN
            INSERT INTO audits(auditTable,auditPK,`dateTime`) VALUES ('dogs', NEW.id, NOW());
            SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() INTO @AID;
        END IF;
        INSERT INTO auditFields(auditsId,changeField,oldValue,newValue) VALUES (@AID,'Name',OLD.`name`,NEW.`name`);
    END IF;
    IF NEW.color <> OLD.color THEN
        IF @AID = 0 THEN
            INSERT INTO audits(auditTable,auditPK,`dateTime`) VALUES ('dogs', NEW.id, NOW());
            SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() INTO @AID;
        END IF;
        INSERT INTO auditFields(auditsId,changeField,oldValue,newValue) VALUES (@AID,'Color',OLD.color,NEW.color);
    END IF;
    IF NEW.size <> OLD.size THEN
        IF @AID = 0 THEN
            INSERT INTO audits(auditTable,auditPK,`dateTime`) VALUES ('dogs', NEW.id, NOW());
            SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() INTO @AID;
        END IF;
        INSERT INTO auditFields(auditsId,changeField,oldValue,newValue) VALUES (@AID,'Size',OLD.size,NEW.size);
    END IF;
    IF NEW.hair <> OLD.hair THEN
        IF @AID = 0 THEN
            INSERT INTO audits(auditTable,auditPK,`dateTime`) VALUES ('dogs', NEW.id, NOW());
            SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() INTO @AID;
        END IF;
        INSERT INTO auditFields(auditsId,changeField,oldValue,newValue) VALUES (@AID,'Hair',OLD.hair,NEW.hair);
    END IF;
    IF NEW.age <> OLD.age THEN
        IF @AID = 0 THEN
            INSERT INTO audits(auditTable,auditPK,`dateTime`) VALUES ('dogs', NEW.id, NOW());
            SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() INTO @AID;
        END IF;
        INSERT INTO auditFields(auditsId,changeField,oldValue,newValue) VALUES (@AID,'Age',OLD.age,NEW.age);
    END IF;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

**UPDATE:** A more succinct version utilizing a temp table

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER tg_dogs_upd AFTER UPDATE ON dogs
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS tempAuditFields;
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tempAuditFields(changeField VARCHAR(256),oldValue VARCHAR(256),newValue VARCHAR(256));
    IF NEW.name <> OLD.name THEN
        INSERT INTO tempAuditFields VALUES ('Name',OLD.`name`,NEW.`name`);
    END IF;
    IF NEW.color <> OLD.color THEN
        INSERT INTO tempAuditFields VALUES ('Color',OLD.color,NEW.color);
    END IF;
    IF NEW.size <> OLD.size THEN
        INSERT INTO tempAuditFields VALUES ('Size',OLD.size,NEW.size);
    END IF;
    IF NEW.hair <> OLD.hair THEN
        INSERT INTO tempAuditFields VALUES ('Hair',OLD.hair,NEW.hair);
    END IF;
    IF NEW.age <> OLD.age THEN
        INSERT INTO tempAuditFields VALUES ('Age',OLD.age,NEW.age);
    END IF;

    IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tempAuditFields) > 0 THEN
        INSERT INTO audits(auditTable,auditPK,`dateTime`) VALUES ('dogs', NEW.id, NOW());
        SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() INTO @AID;
        INSERT INTO auditFields(auditsId,changeField,oldValue,newValue)
        SELECT @AID,changeField,oldValue,newValue FROM tempAuditFields;
        DROP TEMPORARY TABLE tempAuditFields;
    END IF;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Thanks, I am very new to triggers, but looks like it will work.

Comment: @user1032531 You're welcome. Give it a try and let me know. It works just fine on my machine.

Comment: @user1032531 See updated answer for a version utilizing a temp table

Comment: Succinct is good!  I will test it.  I am thinking of also adding a timestamp check for the record as a whole.

Comment: Slightly off topic. Do you think I should normalize the table name and field names, and put them in a different table?  If so, should the PK be a surrogate or natural key such as tablename_fieldname?

Comment: @user1032531 Normalizing never hurts for OLTP systems, so do it. I almost always go with surrogates.